# Loading TensorFlow model from remote location

Tags: python, remote-server, tensorflow2.x

Configuration:
TensorFlow 2.3 Python 3.6

How to load the TensorFlow model stored on Google Drive or on any other remote server/location in the Python program?

I am looking for a solution which do not require the downloading of the model and giving the filepath. ie. a solution in which I can directly give the url of my TensorFlow model to load the TensorFlow model. This url is irrespective of Google Drive, i.e. it can be the url of any remote storage/server.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the model to the local device and the load it.

Comment: I am looking for a solution which do not require the downloading of the model and giving the filepath. ie. a solution in which I can directly give the url of my TensorFlow model to load the TensorFlow model. This url is irrespective of Google Drive, i.e. it can be the url of any remote storage/server.